# iPhone how to create a full screen app?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, rendering, fullscreen

I've been trying to create a full screen view. I plan on using core graphics for rendering. I am new to iPhone development so please forgive this basic question.

Here's my setup code;

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    GameView *main_view;
    main_view = [[GameView alloc] initWithFrame:rect ];
    main_view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    self.view = main_view;
    [main_view release];    
}
```

Yet when I run this I get a thin status bar at the top with the time and battery level.

I tried looking for some samples yet all the samples were opengles.

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? And just how to create a full screen view.

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are two methods;

In the info.plist for your application add a `boolean` key `UIStatusBarHidden` and set it to true.

At runtime you can call `setStatusBarHidden` on your application to show/hide the status bar. E.g.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a note here: be sure to add the above code *before* initializing your UIWindow. If you don't, subsequent calls to the bounds won't include the difference in height w/out the status bar.

Comment: [setStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622949-setstatusbarhidden) was deprecated in iOS 9.0, could you update by what it was replaced ? [prefersStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden) ?

Answer (score 13):

Since I just found the answer I was looking for here, I may as well add that the above method is now depreciated.  The modern method is:

`- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to make your `rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`

Answer (score 2):

Add below method in respective view controller

-(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works and it is the easiest

UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance : NO in the .plist