# iPhone status bar showing over the top of UIView

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I'm having an issue removing/hiding the status bar. I have looked at other posts and tried using the following line in my code:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

This seems to work to some extent, however I can still see the status bar, except now it's on top of my view:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I've never come across this problem before.

Comment: Have you tried that: [iPhone how to create a full screen app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620386/iphone-how-to-create-a-full-screen-app)

Comment: Thank you - that helped me resolve the issue!

Comment: You're welcome. Since this is a duplicate, you might want to consider to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In info.plist I added UIStatusBarHidden and I set it to true. This resolved the issue.